# MooTools: How can I replace existing field text with text insert?

Tags: javascript, forms, replace, mootools, field

I've been on this one for a while but no luck so far, however I did get emoticons fully working using code for mootools.

Basically, I have a existing field of

```
<input type="text" class="post_action_input" value="Say Something..." id="emoticons_insert" />
```

And a image underneath containing

```
<img onClick="javascript:$('blove2').fancyShow();" src="./images/user_status_emoticon.jpg" width="25" height="25" />
```

Which triggers a dropdown containing this emoticon DIV that inserts the :alien: text into the field above

```
<div id="blove2"><a href="javascript:;" onClick="InsertText('emoticon1','emoticons_insert'); return false;"><img src="./images/smiley/alien.png" alt="" onClick="javascript:$('blove2').fancyHide();" /></a></div>

<div id="emoticon1" style="display:none;"> :alien: </div>
```

And it works great. However, what is really messing up our users is that our input field contains "Say Something" that dissapeares upon click, reappears on outer click etc. When they click the emoticon, it appends and produces "Say Something...:alien:" and posts just like that. How can I completely clear "Say Something..." while preserving the :alien: text upon clicking a emoticon? We are using MooTools 1.2.

Field insert Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function contentHTML(id, m) {
    var obj = get(id),
        op = '';
    if (m) {
        op += obj.innerHTML;
    } else if (!m) {
        op += (!obj.innerText) ? obj.textContent : obj.innerText;
    }
    return (op);
}

function InsertText(input, output) {
    var text = contentHTML(input, true);
    var ele = get(output);
    ele.value += text;
}
</script>
```

Emoticons drop-down JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    Element.implement({
        fancyShow: function() {
            this.fade('in');
            this.setStyle('display', '');
        },
        fancyHide: function() {
            this.fade('out');
            this.setStyle('display', 'none');
        }
    });
    //$('element').fancyHide(); // FREEZES STATUS INPUT FIELD FOR SOME REASON
});
</script>
```

In other words, how can onClick insert replace "Say Something..." from the field, and insert :alien: successfully? Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Did you try removing the `+` in `ele.value += text;` of the insertText function? That clears the "Say something". Btw, complete this fiddle so its more clear what you have http://jsfiddle.net/D7aZp/

Comment: Ok, did it work as you wanted without the `+` ?, like http://jsfiddle.net/D7aZp/4/

Comment: I have updated the Fiddle. Your suggestion works but how can I preserve text they type, and insert the emoticon with their input text, but still replace "Say Something..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, with less code.
In this suggestion I use Mootools's [OverText](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/OverText), instead of your inline onfocus/onclick/onblur/value which will not work. OverText comes with Mootools More and in the fiddle I used mootools 1.3.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="post_action_input" title="Say something..." id="emoticons_insert" />
<img onClick="javascript:$('blove2').fancyShow();" src="/images/user_status_emoticon.jpg" width="25" height="25" />
<div id="blove2">
    <img src="/images/smiley/alien.png" data-name=":alien:" class="emoticon" alt="" />
</div>
```

Mootools

```
function InsertText(input, output) {
    var ele = document.id(output);
    ele.value += input;
    ele.fireEvent('change');
}
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    Element.implement({
        fancyShow: function () {
            this.fade('in');
            this.setStyle('display', '');
        },
        fancyHide: function () {
            this.fade('out');
            this.setStyle('display', 'none');
        }
    });
    // Labels over the inputs.
    document.getElements('input').each(function (el) {
        new OverText(el);
    });
    document.getElements('.emoticon').addEvent('click', function () {
        var icon_name = this.get('data-name');
        InsertText(icon_name, 'emoticons_insert');
        this.getParent().fancyHide();
    });
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xqp3R/2/)**

Comment: Overlapping text, "Say Something.." is still not, not replaced by emoticon value. This is the problem.

Comment: @CodyTapping, updated demo with `ele.fireEvent('change');` in case you press emoticon first. Typing first was already working to hide the "Say something..."

Comment: Hi there. Sorry late reply. Yes I have successfully tested it. Having a few issues but it is great code, and adds to our continual MooTools support, I appreciate it!

Comment: @CodyTapping, let me know if you need more help with it. Otherwise please click to accept this answer. Glad I could help!

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation, however personally it is a accepted answer for myself. Thank you.

Comment: @CodyTapping, you don't need reputation to accept, just to up-vote. You can click in the "check" grey mark so it will turn green. Nice the answer helped you! Cheers